# Syntax error with simple MsgBox

Tags: vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trXV8.png)

I am just learning VBA program on my own at work.

I have attached a picture of the syntax error.

I keep getting an error at the msgbox.

What did I do wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim firstnum, secondnum As Single
firstnum = Cells(1, 1).Value
secondnum = Cells(1, 2).Value
If firstnum > secondnum Then
MsgBox " The first number is greater than the second number"
If firstnum < secondnum Then
MsgBox " The first number is less than the second number"
Else
MsgBox " They are euqal "
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your issue is your quotation marks should be " not〝, never use primed quotation marks in vba (as far as I know).

Comment: Also, surprisingly if you use `MsgBox 〝test〞` without the space in front of test you'll get no warning and a blank string.  That's a very unfortunate start to programming.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim firstnum, secondnum As Single
firstnum = Cells(1, 1).Value
secondnum = Cells(1, 2).Value
    If firstnum > secondnum Then
    MsgBox " The first number is greater than the second number"
   
    If firstnum < secondnum Then
    MsgBox " The first number is less than the second number"
    
    Else
    MsgBox " They are euqal "

End If
End Sub                                                                                                                                                                        
"Block If without End If"

Comment: Did you accidentally comment out your `End If` line?

Comment: yes i did and now i am getting block if wihtout end if error...

Comment: You should include your code and the error message in the text of your post.

Comment: hi silentsod, I will do that next time. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: To include your code in a formatted way use four spaces in the front of it. Or after pasting it, select it and hit control+K --- but obviously if you commented out your `End If` line you need to un-comment it. Also you can edit your question to include your formatted code now, rather than next time.

Comment: For your second `If` you should use `ElseIf` instead. Take a look at VBA conditional statements to learn more http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Conditional-Statements.html or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: Oh!! It worked, Thanks Cody !!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your programming adventures.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in order to check you program. The first thing i noticed is that you are using two `if` statements and only closing the first one, i mean for every `if` you need an `end if` statement. Second, i think two `if` are unnecessary since you can use `elseif` statement

```
Private Sub test()
Dim firstnum, secondnum As Single
 firstnum = Cells(1, 1).Value
 secondnum = Cells(1, 2).Value
If firstnum > secondnum Then
 MsgBox " The first number is greater than the second number"
ElseIf firstnum < secondnum Then
 MsgBox " The first number is less than the second number"
Else
 MsgBox " They are euqal "
End If
End Sub
```

Finally as an advice try always using indentation.